# Some well-known theorems about maximal-minimal

Tags: solution-verification, maxima-minima

Given a partially ordered set $\left(P,\le\right)$ and a subset $S$ of $P$:

**Theorem (I)**: If maximum $S$ does exist, it's unique.

Proof:

> Assume there are two maximum of $S$ denoted $g_1,g_2$, then by definition of maximum it follows $g_{1}\le g_{2}$ and $g_{2}\le g_{1}$, using the anti-symmetric property of $S$ implies $g_{1}=g_{2}$.

**Theorem (II)**: Every maximum is a maximal.

Proof:

> A maximal is by definition greater than or equals to any other element that can be compared with , a maximum is by definition greater than or equals to any other element in $S$,clearly maximum is stronger than maximal and maximal is a generalization of maximum, hence the result follows.

**Theorem (III)** : If maximum of $S$ exists then the maximal of $S$ is unique.

Proof:

> From definition of maximum it follows that maximum of $S$ denoted $g$ is greater than or equals to any other element $s$ in $S$, specially when $s$ is a maximal of $S$ , so $s\le g$, also since $s$ is the maximal of $S$ so by definition of maximal it follows that $s$ is greater than or equals to any other element in $S$ specially $g$ ,e.g. $g\le s$, concludes $g=s$ , since $g$ is unique by Theorem **I)** implies $s$ is also unique.

Since this is true for all partial-order relations and since partial-order relation is a generalization of a total-order relation hence in a total order relation maximum and maximal coincides.

**Theorem (IV)**: The set of maximal elements of a subset S is always an anti-chain, that is, no two different maximal elements of S are comparable.

Proof:

> Using theorem **III)** follows a subset $S$ of a partially ordered set $\left(P,\le\right)$ can have more than one maximal element if it does not have a greatest element, for the sake of contradiction assume there exist two maximal elements such that they are comparable, it means that they are related to each other via $\le$ and this contradicts the fact that the two elements are indeed maximal.

I'm not sure if all of the proofs are right, can someone please verify? and please let me know if there are other well-known theorems about this object.

Comment: "clearly maximum is stronger than maximum".. You meant of course "clearly maximum is stronger than *maximal*". Further looks fine. IV is short: if two maximals are comparable then they must coincide on base of antisymmetry.

Comment: It might be clearer to write "greatest element" for "maximum"

Comment: @drhab, yes that's an error and I will fix it, and you say if $m_1,m_2$ are two maximal elements then based on the definition of maximal $m_{1}\le m_{2}$ because $m_1$ is greater than or equals to any other element that can be compared with (with respect to  $\le$), the same can be said for $m_2$ and since $m_{1}\le m_{2}$ and $m_{2}\le m_{1}$ so implies every two maximal elements that are related to each other are the same or if they are not related then they are distinct?

Comment: If maximals $m_1,m_2$ are comparable, i.e. $m_1<m_2\vee m_1=m_2\vee m_2<m_1$ then the possibilities $m_1<m_2$ and $m_2<m_1$ automatically fall away because they contradict the maximality of $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively. So $m_1=m_2$ remains as only option.

Comment: @drhab, I got it, thank you for helping, and do you know any other important (not so complicated) theorems about maxima/minimal?

Comment: Well, there is [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) of course that assures that a partial ordered set contains a maximal if every chain has an upper bound. IMV a very import tool in mathematics.

Comment: @drhab,If we consider the $S=\left\{s \in \mathbb Q\ :s^{2}\le\sqrt{2}\right\}$, then in my opinion this set does not have any maximal or minimal , since neither $\sqrt{2}$ nor 
 $-\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number.,but Wikipedia says the set has many maximal element and many minimal elements

Comment: I agree with you and also Wikipedia agrees with you [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements#Existence_and_uniqueness). Can you provide a link?

Comment: @drhab, indeed my source is your link, so I guess there was a misunderstanding and it's ok now, there is a question that I've been thinking about for a long time, can we look at local extrema as maximal/minimal where our partially ordered set (more preciously our totally ordered set ) in the set of real numbers $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Sorry but I need more context for this in order to understand what you mean. Also it is not appropriate to handle that in comments here. If the question really interests you then of course you can post it on this site.