# Are bottom and top the synonyms of minimum and maximum of the partially ordered set respectively

Tags: maxima-minima

Wikipedia states:

> The least and greatest element of the whole partially ordered set plays a special role and is also called bottom and top, or zero (0) and unit (1), or ⊥ and ⊤, respectively. If both exists, the poset is called a bounded poset.

Greatest and least elements of a partially ordered set does not always exist but if they exist then they are unique and based on [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536669/some-well-known-theorems-about-maximal-minimal?noredirect=1#comment7273772_3536669) maximal and minimal of this set are are also unique, I'm wondering if these terminologies **bottom** and **top** are the synonyms of **minimum** and **maximum** of the partially ordered set respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\top$ and $\bot$ are symbols for the maximum and the minimum element of the poset respectively.

Most of the time, these symbols are used for boolean algebras (remember that the relation $x \leqslant y : \Leftrightarrow xy = x$ defines a partial order on a boolean algebra). There, $\top$ and $\bot$ (resp.) correspond to the $1$ and $0$ of the algebra. These symbols were chosen because they correspond (resp.) to the tautology and the antilogy.

Comment: so a bounded poset is a set that has its top and bottom or equivalently it contains its maximum and minimum resp?

Comment: @user715522 Yes. I would say "has a maximal element" because if you say "contains its maximum" then you implicitly assume that this maximum is given by the context.