# Proving some of theorems about upper/lower sets.

Tags: relations, solution-verification

Given a subset $S$ of a partially ordered set $P$ associated with a  partial order denoted $\le $, then $S$ is called an upper set if :
$$\forall x \in S,\forall y \in P :x \le y \implies y \in S$$

The lower set can be defined analogously.

Prove the following theorems:

> **I)** Every partially ordered set is an upper set (lower set) of itself.

Setting $S=P$ in the previous definition yields:

$$\forall x \in P,\color{blue}{\forall y \in P} :x \le y \implies \color{blue}{y \in P}$$
Implies $P$ is an upper set of itself.

$$\color{red}{\forall x \in P},\forall y \in P :x \le y \implies \color{red}{x \in P}$$
Implies $P$ is a lower set of itself.

This is indeed a relation which is trivially true.

---

> **II)** The intersection and union of upper sets is an upper set.

Given two subsets $S,A$ of two (not necessarily equal) partially ordered sets $(P,\le),(V,\le)$ respectively, the intersection of these two sets is either an empty set or it is not, if the first case happens then their intersection is trivially an upper set, for the second case their intersection is a non-empty set , since this set contained in both $P,V$ implies it should be an upper set.
The union can be proven analogously.

---

> **III)** The complement of any upper set ( resp. lower set) is a lower set ( resp. upper set).

Given a subset $S$ of a partially ordered set $(P,\le)$, by definition:

$$\forall x \in S,\forall y \in P :x \le y \implies y \in S$$

The complement of $S$ is a set $S^c$ containing elements not contained in $S$, e.g.:

$$S^c=\left\{s:s∉S \right\}$$

This is where I have a problem and cannot continue.

---

> **IV)** The minimal elements of any upper set form an antichain. Conversely any antichain A determines an upper set.

I know that the set of maximal/ minimal elements of a partially ordered set is an antichain,but I cannot claim since an upper set $S$ is a subset of a partially ordered set $(P,\le)$, hence $S$ is a partially ordered set itself, because if $S$ is an empty subset then the reflexivity property of partial order relation $\le$ would not follow, so how should I prove that?(and the converse)

Can someone check the validity of my proofs and also prove the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

**I)**

Seems fine

**II)**

I'd say this is too hasty to be a proof. First of all, I would only consider upper sets of the same partially ordered set, so let $A,B\subset P$ be upper sets. If $x\in A\cap B$ and $y\geq x$, then $y\in A$ because $A$ is an upper set and $y\in B$ because $B$ is an upper set, so $y\in A\cap B$. Thus $A\cap B$ is an upper set. On the other hand, if $x\in A\cup B$ and $y\geq x$, then if $x\in A$ we get $y\in A$ and if $x\notin A$, then $x\in B$, so $y\in B$, which shows that $y\in A\cup B$.

**III)**

Let $S$ be an upper set, and let $x\in P\setminus S=S^c$. If $y\leq x$, we have to prove that $y\in S^c$, so assume the contrary: if $y\notin S^c$, then $y\in S$, so by $S$ being an upper set and $y\leq x$ we get $x\in S$, contradiction.

**IV)**

If $x,y$ are two minimal elements of any upper set, and $x$ and $y$ are comparable, then $x\leq y$ because $x$ is minimal, as well as $y\leq x$ because $y$ is minimal. Thus any two comparable minimal elements of an upper set must be equal to each other.

The difficult part is showing that any antichain *determines* an upper set: given two different antichains, closing them upwards will yield two different upper sets. Let $A,B$ be two antichains, let 
\begin{align*}
S=\{x\in P\mid \exists y\in A(y\leq x)\}\\
T=\{x\in P\mid \exists y\in B(y\leq x)\}
\end{align*} 
be the upper sets determined by $A$ and $B$ respectively, and without loss of generality let $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. If there is some $y\in B$ such that $x\leq y$, then we see that $x\in S$ and $y\in S$, but $x\notin T$, since $T$ contains no elements below $y$ (otherwise $B$ would contain some element distinct from $y$ that is comparable to $y$). On the other hand, if there is some $y\in B$ such that $y\leq x$, then $y\in T$ and $y\notin S$, for similar reasons. Finally, if $x$ is incomparable to all elements of $B$, then $x\in S$ and $x\notin T$, since $x$ is not comparable to any element of $B$.

Note that an empty partially ordered set still satisfies the reflexivity property: for all elements $x$ in the empty set we have $x\leq x$ vacuously.

Comment: For **II)** I think letting $A,B$ to be subsets of two not necessarily equal partially ordered sets would still follow your proof, since the main structure of your proof does not use this fact (you just mentioned once that $A,B \subset P$), also can we state that:$$\color{red}{\text{The intersection and union of lower sets is a lower set?}}$$

Comment: Well, technically you could talk about the intersection of two subsets of different posets, but whenever you'll use that there should be some alarm bells going off, since it's highly unusual to compare subsets of different posets as if they belong to the same. And yes, lower sets are completely analogous to upper sets. One easy argument to see this is to consider the relation $\geq$ instead of $\leq$: this makes any lower set an upper set and any upper set a lower set.

Comment: @and for the final case can you please explain why did you made two upper sets $S,P$? and what is the final conclusion? (indeed I cannot understand the strategy which has been used to proof the converse)

Comment: The antichain $A$ defines an upper set by taking all elements larger than some element in $A$. This is the set $S$. Another antichain $B$ that is different from $A$ defines $T$ in a similar way. What I showed is that since $A$ and $B$ are different antichains, also the upper sets $S$ and $T$ are different.

Comment: In other words, each upper set is defined by an antichain, and each antichain is defined by an upper set.

Comment: why you did not used $A$ as an antichain and then showing that $A$ is an upper bound? I mean why did you use another antichain $B$?

Comment: @user715522 Because the thing you want to prove is that *different* antichains define *different* upper sets. You need at least two different things to show that, right?

Comment: Can you please show me an example of the converse?

Comment: I tried like that Let $$P=\left\{\left\{\right\},\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{3\right\},\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{1,3\right\},\left\{2,3\right\},\left\{1,2,3\right\}\right\}$$,and $$A=\left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\}\right\},B=\left\{\left\{2\right\},\left\{3\right\}\right\}$$ Using the definition follows: :$$S=\left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{1,3\right\},\left\{2,3\right\},\left\{1,2,3\right\}\right\}$$ and $$T=\left\{\left\{2\right\},\left\{3\right\},\left\{1,2\right\},\left\{1,3\right\},\left\{2,3\right\},\left\{1,2,3\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104659/discussion-between-vsotvep-and-user715522).

Comment: Can we say: $$\color{blue}{\text{ The minimal/maximal elements of any upper/lower set form an antichain}}$$ And then since an upper/lower set denoted $\mathbb S$ is a subset of a partially ordered set hence it's a partially ordered set and since the set of maximal/minimal elements of a partially ordered set forms an antichain, so does the set of maximal/minimal elements of $\mathbb S$?

Comment: @user715522 I don't see how that's efficient, since you have to prove that $\Bbb S$ is a partially ordered set, and that the maximal elements of a partially set form an antichain. Proving the latter claim is the main part, and it's basically what I did in my proof.

Comment: Well I mean we can prove the blue theorem using the fact that the  The minimal/maximal elements of any partially ordered set form an antichain (your proof is right, I'm just saying proving the blue theorem can be done using [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536669/some-well-known-theorems-about-maximal-minimal) more general theorem)

Comment: @user715522 But the proof that the maximal elements form an antichain is exactly the same, it's not a more general theorem.

Comment: Anyway, I think this is a bit of a silly discussion